# Find where free is called on a given pointer type

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm converting a type from a C-style struct to a C++-style struct; I'm adding a member which will force the type to need a constructor, and I must therefore switch from `malloc` and `free` to `new` and `delete`. I can find everywhere the type is allocated (due to the conventions of this codebase) by looking for `sizeof(TYPE)`.

Is there any way I can locate all the instances where pointers of that type are passed to `free`? I realise that, since the argument to `free` is `void*` that's not a guarantee I've found everywhere the type is freed.

For instance, can I overload `free` somehow so that I'll get a compilation error wherever `free(TYPE*)` is called, but not anywhere else?

Comment: So the conventions of the code base are are tight enough to ensure always `TYPE *ptr = malloc(sizeof(TYPE));` and never `TYPE *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));`, but not tight enough to ensure that if you find the point where something is allocated, you can work out who is responsible for freeing it. Whoever set those priorities hasn't done you any favours ;-p

Comment: Just a thought -- if instead of replacing `malloc/free` with `new/delete` you replace the allocations with `make_shared`, then the compiler errors (and your fixes for them) will propagate out to any code that uses a pointer to the object because you'll have to replace it with `shared_ptr`. Therefore including the frees. At least, assuming nobody does anything really sneaky like using `&*`, which would silently smuggle a raw pointer out of the shared_ptr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can I overload free somehow

You can certainly give it a go. For example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>

namespace my {
    class TYPE { };
    template <typename T>
    void free(T *ptr) { std::iterator_traits<T>::attempt_to_free_TYPE; }
}

using std::malloc;
using std::free;
using my::TYPE;

int main() {
    TYPE *ptr = (TYPE *) malloc(sizeof(TYPE));
    free(ptr);
}
```

Thanks to ADL, that call to `free` is to `my::free`, so the code fails to compile. Obviously this wouldn't catch `free((void*)ptr);`, since calls to `free` with arguments other than `my::TYPE*` are unaffected.

As I've written it, there need to not be any calls to `free` inside namespace `my`, or in code that has `using namespace my;`. So you might want to use a newly-invented namespace for the purpose. Or write a less catch-all template, I improvised that one.

It also doesn't catch fully-qualified calls to `std::free`. It's undefined behavior to overload `std::free` (or anything in namespace std), but if necessary you'd probably get away with it just for the purpose of finding call sites. Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct allowed_to_free {
    enum { value };
};
template <>
struct allowed_to_free<TYPE> {};

namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    void free(T *ptr) {
        allowed_to_free<T>::value; 
        free((void*)ptr); 
    };
}
```

Comment: You can do better.  Make `my::free` a template function that fails to compile when instantiated.  Now it fails before linking...

Comment: Ooh, I like it. I'll give it a whirl!

Answer (score 0):

Use valgrind: if you're willing to do the check in runtime consider using valgrind to perform this kind of task.

Valgrind will tell you when you have incorrectly `free`'d a `new()`-allocated object.

As the OP is not in Linux but in VS I guess there tools similar to valgrind.

Another option is to use a static-analyzer such as coverity or clang-analyze.

Comment: He wants to do the opposite - to find the usages of free not of new and delete.

Comment: It's the other way around - he needs a c++ parameter-specific free() overload

Comment: Oh. I'll adapt my question.

Comment: I can't feasibly do this at runtime; and I'm on Windows under VS - I can't use Valgrind

Comment: @Chowlett do you have access to a descent static-analyzer?

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly... However, you can pull a trick to find all places where such (incorrectly initialized) instances are used. Just make all the members of your former struct - now class - private. The compiler will raise an error whereever these fields/members are used. This will give you a starting point to further analyze the code and wipe out any malloc/free calls.

Comment: This seems highly impractical, and doesn't solve the problem. With all members private, this will give you all places members are used, but not necessarily any of the places where a pointer to the type is handled.

Comment: If no members are used, initialization by malloc is not a problem, as long as no memory leaks are present ( but that's a separate question). So I disagree with you, that's the only way to clean out all undefined behavior at once (accepted answer has some rough edges too)

Comment: And more - if you make sure the class members are not used anywhere, any malloc/free pair left become perfectly legal operation (who knows why I might want to allocate X bytes) - and will be optimized away by a good compiler anyways.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the problem is that the question is not about how to get rid of undefined behaviour due to `malloc`/`free`. The question is how to locate calls to `free`, since the type has gained a new member which will require allocation via `new`. Given that context, your suggestion doesn't really help answer the question. There is no telling how many instances of the type are allocated or in how many places its members are accessed. Going through that entire list of error messages in the hope of stumbling across their matching deallocations doesn't sound useful.

Comment: Ok, it's just different understanding of the question :) I've understood the question as the OP trying to ensure correctness of program after replacing struct with class. Overloading "malloc"/"free" is just one of the ways to do it.